# Django admin tabular inline lookup select dropdown box for a very large queryset

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, modelchoicefield, django-select2

I have a django admin tabular inline, in which I have `form = ProdForm` which holds a `modelchoicefield` select box as follows;

```
class ProdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    productid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.filter(active=True),
                                       widget=Select2(select2attrs={"width": "400px"}), )
```

as you can see, I am using the easy_select2 module, that is enabling providing me with a look up field too.

However, if I try to load this in the corresponding tabularInLine, it never loads because there is a very high number of records (suppose millions). Therefore loading the entire queryset is not possible. I need to find a way to do this so people using the admin can search the object they need, suppose by a name which is one of the attributes on the `Product model`.

An idea is to keep the search box but not load the queryset initially and hit the db when there are, for example 3 or more letters in the search field, that could maybe work. However, that would include some js that I am not really familiar with and I would prefer some pythonic/django way of doing this.

Or maybe there is a nice django way but I haven't found it and I am at my wits end.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ajax.

You can call `ajax` when you submit search bar, next search your record in `view.py`, and at the end display result in console or template.

This is a general example:

file.js

```
$("#search").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: path_to_view,
        data: {'data':data_from_search_bar},
        success: function(response){
            var result = response['result']
            console.log(result)
        }
        error: 'some_func..'
    })
});
```

view.py

```
def get_result(request):
     if request.is_ajax and request.method =="GET":
         response_data = request.GET['data']
         product = ProductModel.objects.get(name=response_data)# or others attrs
         return JsonResponse({'result':product},status=200)
```

Read here more about ajax:

[CFE](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

[pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django)

[geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-ajax-request-in-django/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is certainly a useful hint. However, suppose there is the following name: "Asus Zenfone 7, 8GB/128GB" This approach would yield this object only if the name was entered in full. I could bypass this by __icontains but what if I don't want the user to submit/hit enter but to load the possible icontains results as they type?

Comment: In your view try: `products = ProductModel.objects.filter(name__contains=response_data)` and if you want to do it every time when someone write somethink into the input search field insted of `submit` use: `$("#search").bind('input propertychange', function() {`

Comment: also then in your js write `for (var product in response['result']){ content }` because repsonse will be a querydict. I'm not sure how querydict is displayed in js but in your view you can also put this: `pr_array=[]   ` `for i in products: pr_dict.append(i.name)` `products = {'result': pr_array}`

Comment: I don't use views for this as this is django admin inline, I am now trying to extend the default template for this so I guess this all will have to be placed there

Comment: To edit admin panel check here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)