# I want to add product in cart without refreshing page with AJAX and Django

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, ajax

Nothing will ne happened when I submit product in the the cart.  I want to use AJAX without refreshing page.
When I submit the console message will be displayed.
I'm trying to use AJAX first.
Trying to add product in the cart without refreshing page.
I need help please :)

***Views Django***

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

    form = CartProductForm(request.POST)
       
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                quantity=cd['quantity'],
                update_quantity=cd['update_qt']
                )
                
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

***Form***

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class CartProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(initial=1)
    update_qt = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

***HTML Code***

```
<form action="{% url "..." %}"  method="post" data-id="{{ ... }}" class="form-order" id="form">
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a data-id="{{ ... }}" class="buy-product"><button>BUY</button></a>
</form>
```

***JS Code***

```
        $(".buy-product").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var product_id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            var quantity = 1
            console.log(product_id)
            console.log(quantity)

            data = {
                'product_id': product_id,
                'quantity': quantity
            }
            var point='/cart/add/'+product_id+'/'
            
            $.ajax({
                headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                url: point,
                type: 'POST',


                data: data,

                success: function(data){
                    console.log('success')
                    console.log(csrftoken)
                    
                }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add csrftoken in data: `{csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken}`. Also I don't see when you initialize your variables, but I think is just example. Check this answer for more: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217567/14126078)

Comment: I have error 500 when I click add is_ajax method in my views.

Comment: Just one think. I've just seen that you put into data `point` hardcoded url with some id. In your case it is not necessary to put `product_id` parameter, but if you prefer to stay with that just check this [answer](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/70080/how-to-pass-parameter-to-ajax-urls-django).
 I want to notice that your way to solve the problem is much harder than just deleting url `product_id` parameter. Look that you are already sending this variable in data. Why duplicate that?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent form from refreshig the page and then do whatever you need with your JS code:

```
<form action="{% url "..." %}"  method="post" data-id="{{ ... }}" class="form-order" id="form" onsubmit="myFunction(event)">
...
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing will be happened when I do this.

Comment: That's actually what it's doing - prevent the default behavior for form on submit, including page reload, and let's you handle it yourself in whatever way you need.

Comment: How to prevent the default behavior of the form? PreventDefault allows not to reload the page.

Comment: Default behavior of the form is sending post request, after click on submit button, that causing page reload. When you use `preventDefault` you are left on your own with sending post request and hadling response.